# populate dropdown using a textbox asp.net

Tags: asp.net

[image][image]How to populate a drop down when user enters some text in text box, i have tried using text changed event  in the text box control it works, but needs to click twice the drop down, when i clicked first it loads the data and drop drown gets closed, then i again click it shows 
i used asp text box and asp drop down

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">  
        </asp:TextBox>
```

---

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    DropDownList1.Items.Clear()
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim icount As Integer
    icount = DropDownList1.Items.Count
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("Select")
    DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = icount
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: are you trying to add only one value + `select` option to the on the `text changed` dropdown?

Comment: You can use `OnTextChanged="DropDownList1"` in your textbox property

Comment: i getting populated in the dropdown, but the dropdown getting closed on first time click , when i leave from the textbox

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

and then :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(this.TextBox1.Text);
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            this.DropDownList1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Selected Value Is :" + this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    }
```

Please let me know if you have some difficulty.

Comment: my code  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">  
        </asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="492px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

Comment: Try writing Autopostback = "True" event in your dropdown list in the manner that I have written above.

Comment: i getting populated in the dropdown, but the dropdown getting closed on first time click , when i leave from the textbox

Comment: Can you please send an image on how it is getting closed?

Comment: I think as soon as you write something in the textbox, it goes to the textchange event and there as dropdown list is to be cleared all the elements are getting cleared and only Select appears. Please paste the code that i have given and try out. 

It should work.

Comment: showing error : Input string was not in a correct format. Dim count As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Me.TextBox1.Text)

Answer (score 0):

Example : txtCity.text = "Mysore,Bangalore,Delhi"

```
protected void txtCity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] _cities=this.txtCity.text.split(',');
    int _maxCities = _cities.count();
    for (int _item = 1; _item <= _maxCities; _item++)
    {
        this.ddlCity.Items.Add(_item.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: able to add in the dropdown, but when i click first time it get closed, because of loading data